# VBA Excel Macro write file using UTF-8 encoding

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, utf-8

I'm creating a macro in excel that processes a spreadsheet and writes the content (text) to a file. I need this file to be encoded as UTF-8. I've tried opening the file as unicode using OpenTextFile(... TristateTrue) and StrConv(.. vbUnicode) but those only convert it to UTF-16. I've searched everywhere online and can't find anything. Is this even possible?

thanks

Comment: Searching for VBScript/VB6 which are very closely related is often helpful; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125778/unicode-to-utf-8

Comment: thanks! that worked. I'm new to vb so i didn't know you could use the same command for it

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim fsT As Object
Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fsT.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
fsT.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
fsT.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
fsT.WriteText "special characters: äöüß"
fsT.SaveToFile sFileName, 2 'Save binary data To disk
```

Reference:
    [Save text file UTF-8 encoded with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524703/save-text-file-utf-8-encoded-with-vba)

Comment: If you are referencing another SO answer, then this is probably best marked as a duplicate.