# VB Script accented characters coming out as "Chinese" looking script?

Tags: vba, vbscript, character-encoding

I'm writing a VB script to replace words in a word doc.

The crux of the code is:

```
strEuropeanOld="European"
strEuropeanNew="Européen"
```

I then replace the word:

```
If InStr(FileText, strEuropeanOld) Then
    WriteLog("Replacing " & strEuropeanOld & " with " & strEuropeanNew & ".")
    FileText = Replace(FileText, strEuropeanOld, strEuropeanNew)
    WriteLog("Text replaced")
Else
    WriteLog(strEuropeanOld & " was not found in the file.")
    strCount2 = strCount2 +1
End If
```

All works perfectly for words without accents e.g. é.

However those with accents come out as `Europ饮` rather than `Européen` after translation!

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the encoding used. Check this link, they are talking about a similar issue. [Unicode to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125778/unicode-to-utf-8)

Hope this helps.